# mvc3 jqgrid readonly fields on edit/addform

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, readonly

I have a jqGrid using Form Editing. I would like Some of the fields to be Readonly in 'Edit' mode but not in 'Add' mode.  I have tried some of the suggestions I have found elsewhere to solve this(see example below), but still cannot get it to work!

If anyone can help I shall be most grateful!

In The below grid I am attempting to set 'LogonName' to ReadOnly in 'edit' mode, and NOT in 'Add' mode.

```
$('#jpgCustomers').jqGrid({
     url: '@Url.Action("Customers")',
     datatype: 'json',
     mtype: 'POST',
     colNames: ['Name', 'FullName', 'Description'],
     colModel: [
                { name: 'LogonName', index: 'LogonName', align: 'left', width:80, editable:true, search:true, stype:'text',editrules:{required:true}},
                { name: 'FullName', index: 'FullName', align: 'left',width: 200, editable:true, search:true, stype:'text',editrules:{required:true}},
                { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', align: 'left', width: 300, editable:true, search:true, stype:'text'}
               ]

    //..

$("#jpgCustomers").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jpgpCustomers', 
        { add: true, del: true, edit: true, search: false},
        //edit form
        { width: '500', 
          editCaption: 'Edit Customer',
          url: '@Url.Action("EditCustomer")', 
          reloadAfterSubmit: true, 
          closeAfterEdit: true,
          //always start from a new form
          recreateForm: true,
          beforeShowForm: function(form) {
                  //center the edit dialog on screen
                  var dlgDiv = $("#editmod" + jpgCustomers.id);
                  CenterDialog(dlgDiv);
                  $("#jpgCustomers").jqGrid('setColProp','LogonName',{editoptions: {readonly:'readonly'}});
              }
        },
        //Add form
        { width: '500', 
          addCaption: 'Add Customer',
          url: '@Url.Action("CreateCustomer")', 
          reloadAfterSubmit: true, 
          closeAfterEdit: true,
          beforeShowForm: function(form) {
                  var dlgDiv = $("#editmod" + jpgCustomers.id);
                  CenterDialog(dlgDiv);
                  $("#jpgCustomers").jqGrid('setColProp','LogonName',{editoptions: {readonly:false}});
           }
        },
        //Delete form
        { width: '250', 
          url: '@Url.Action("DeleteCustomer")',
          beforeShowForm: function(form) {
          //center the delete dialog on screen
          var dlgDiv = $("#delmod" + jpgCustomers.id);
          CenterDialog(dlgDiv);
          //change the Delete confirmation message
          var sel_id = $("#jpgCustomers").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow')
          $("td.delmsg", form).html("Delete User <b>" + $("#jpgCustomers").jqGrid('getCell', sel_id,'LogonName') + "</b>?");
        }
     }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after Hours of testing and retesting, and trying various things, I have stumbled on the solution!

I have made a couple of changes to the above code, and not Entirely sure which has been the overriding answer to the problem but here is what I did:

**1)** Moved The call to 'SetColProp' from the *beforeShowForm* into the *beforeInitData* function

**2)** put beforeInitData before beforeShowForm - I don;t think This actually makes any difference, but it works, so I'm leaving it there!

**3)** Included a *recreateForm:true* in The Add form section (I already had one in the edit section)

I think point 1 and 3 made the difference, but I couldn;'t tell you why!

**Heres the working navGrid section** altered from The Question:

```
$("#jpgCustomers").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jpgpCustomers', 
    { add: true, del: true, edit: true, search: false},
    //edit form
    { width: '500', 
      editCaption: 'Edit Customer',
      url: '@Url.Action("EditCustomer")', 
      reloadAfterSubmit: true, 
      closeAfterEdit: true,
      //always start from a new form
      recreateForm: true,
      beforeInitData: function(form) {
          $("#jpgCustomers").jqGrid('setColProp','LogonName',{editoptions: {readonly:'readonly'}});
      },
      beforeShowForm: function(form) {
              //center the edit dialog on screen
              var dlgDiv = $("#editmod" + jpgCustomers.id);
              CenterDialog(dlgDiv);
      }
    },
    //Add form
    { width: '500', 
      addCaption: 'Add Customer',
      url: '@Url.Action("CreateCustomer")', 
      reloadAfterSubmit: true, 
      closeAfterEdit: true,
      recreateForm: true,
      beforeInitData: function(form) {
           $("#jpgCustomers").jqGrid('setColProp','LogonName',{editoptions: {readonly:false}});
      },
      beforeShowForm: function(form) {
           var dlgDiv = $("#editmod" + jpgCustomers.id);
           CenterDialog(dlgDiv);
      }
    },
    //Delete form
    { width: '250', 
      url: '@Url.Action("DeleteCustomer")',
      beforeShowForm: function(form) {
      //center the delete dialog on screen
      var dlgDiv = $("#delmod" + jpgCustomers.id);
      CenterDialog(dlgDiv);
      //change the Delete confirmation message
      var sel_id = $("#jpgCustomers").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow')
      $("td.delmsg", form).html("Delete User <b>" + $("#jpgCustomers").jqGrid('getCell', sel_id,'LogonName') + "</b>?");
    }
 }
```

);